# Collective membership text removed from user card between answer deletion and undeletion

Tags: bug, status-planned, deleted-answers, user-card, recognized-members

Today, I posted an answer, deleted it, then undeleted it.

Between the deletion and the undeletion, the text that indicates that I am in the PHP Collective has been removed from under my answer's user card.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77663678/timeline

I reckon this is a bug to be fixed.

[image: Screenshot with irrelevant HTML content removed]